# Difficulty using chai with object methods and context

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai

I have an object with some methods:

```
module.exports = {
  auth: async function() {
    // Load the key
    const key = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./keys/key.json").toString());
    // Auth using the key
    var auth;
    try {
      auth = await google.auth.fromJSON(key);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
    // Add read / write spreadsheets scope to our auth client
    auth.scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"];
    // Create an instance of sheets to a scoped variable
    try {
      this.sheets = await google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    } 
  },
  writeSingleRow: async function(spreadsheetId, sheetName, values, index) {
    // Create the resource for google sheets
    const resource = {
      values
    };
    // Write out to the spreadsheet
    const res = await this.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
      spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
      range: `${sheetName}!A${index + 2}:D${values.length + 1 + index}`,
      valueInputOption: "RAW",
      resource: resource
    });
    //console.log("Updated spreadsheet!");
  },
  readSingleRow: async function(spreadsheetId, sheetName, row) {
    const range = sheetName + "!" + "A" + row + ":" + "AU" + row;

    try {
      const response = (
        await this.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
          spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
          range: range,
          majorDimension: "ROWS",
          valueRenderOption: "UNFORMATTED_VALUE", // TODO: Update placeholder value.
          dateTimeRenderOption: "FORMATTED_STRING" // TODO: Update placeholder value.
        })
      ).data;
      // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
      return response;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
};
```

And I am trying to test each one. The problem is that the read and write methods need to have parameters sent to them and there doesn't seem to be a way to do that.

This is what I have tried:

```
//readSingleRow
describe("readSingleRow", () => {
    it("should not throw and return an object with \'values\' property", (done) => {
        expect(sheets.readSingleRow(spreadsheetId,sheetName,row)).to.not.throw();
        done();
    });
});
```

and

```
describe("readSingleRow", () => {
    it("should not throw and return an object with \'values\' property", (done) => {
        var values = sheets.readSingleRow(spreadsheetId,sheetName,row);
        expect(values).to.be.an(object);

        done();
    });
});
```

Nothing works. How can I pass parameters to this function?

Alternatively, if I'm way off the mark here then what am I supposed to be doing? Surely I should be able to just test the calling of a function with parameters. Seems pretty straight-forward unless I am missing some monumental feature of testing.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED:

Turns out I made two mistakes:

1. I was mixing promises and callbacks in mocha. I removed done() callback.
2. It was the wrong data type (I had checked the returned value previously and it was console.logging an object)

   ```
   describe("readSingleRow", function() {
       it("should not throw and return an object with \'values\' property", async function(){
           await sheets.auth();
           const values = await sheets.readSingleRow(spreadsheetId,sheetName,row);
           expect(values.values).to.be.array();            
   });
   ```

   })